# issue while kendo UI with angularjs and require.js

Tags: angularjs, require

I am using kendo UI with angularjs and require.js
I have not added "kendo.all.min.js" to my project. 
I am downloading js as per requirements.
Everything was working fine while using version * Kendo UI v2014.2.903
Then I upgraded to new version Kendo UI v2015.1.429 
Then I found following issues

1. pie chard completely broken. Getting error

> "Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M5 5 L NaN 5 NaN 160 5
>   160Z" in kendo.drawing.min.js"

2. Start animation on bar chart is missing ( Animation :- raising bar from 0 to particular value )
   following is my main.js file

   ```
   require.config({
   baseUrl: 'js',
   waitSeconds: 60,
   paths: {        
       moment: 'vendor/moment.min',
       k: "vendor/kendo_new",
       cryptojs: "vendor/CryptoJS-3.1.2",
       signalR: 'vendor/signalR/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min',
       noext: 'vendor/noext/noext',
       bootstrapAng: 'vendor/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min',
       dateP: 'vendor/daterangepicker/date',
       datePicker: 'vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.jQuery.min',
       dateFormat: 'vendor/daterangepicker/date.format.min',
       directory: 'controllers/directoryController',
       addUpdateContactCtr: 'controllers/addUpdateContactController',
       noContactCtr: 'controllers/noContactController',
       outlookSyncInfoCtr: 'controllers/outlookSyncInfoController',
       eventWatchlistCtr: 'controllers/eventWatchlistController',
       notificationsPopupCtr: 'controllers/notificationsPopupController',
       changePwdCtr: 'controllers/changePwdController',
       loggedOutCtr: 'controllers/loggedOutController',
       mathUtil: 'vendor/math/math.min',
       redactor: 'vendor/redactor/redactor',
       redactor_9_x: 'vendor/redactor/angular-redactor-9.x'
   },
   shim: {
       app: {
           deps: ['k/kendo.scheduler.min', "k/kendo.window.min", 'k/kendo.grid.min', "k/kendo.tabstrip.min"]
       }
   }
   });

   require(
   [        
       'app',
       'routeResolver',
       'vendor/angucomplete-alt/angucomplete-alt.min',
        "k/kendo.dataviz.chart.min",
        "k/kendo.autocomplete.min",
        "k/kendo.core.min",
        "k/kendo.angular.min",
        "k/kendo.editable.min",
        "k/kendo.combobox.min",
        "k/kendo.datepicker.min",
        "k/kendo.numerictextbox.min",
        "cryptojs/aes.min",
        "cryptojs/sha256.min",
        "bootstrapAng",
        "dateP",
        "datePicker",
        "dateFormat"
   ],
   function () {
       angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
   });
   ```

I don't understand why above code is working fine with older version but not working with new version.
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Add chart data to question. I think format of the data that is being passed to Chart might have been changed in the current version. Make sure the format is proper.

Comment: format is not changed.
When I add kendo.all.min.js file in app.html file everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It is so weird. 
Problem with date.js conflict.
Replaced new date.js and everything starts working.